# Image Stitching C++

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, image-stitching

I wrote stitching class in **python** to stitch 2 images and it works just fine!

I am trying to convert the code to **C++** but the results are not the same after the warping part.

Python Code

```
result = cv2.warpPerspective(self.img1, Ht.dot(M_left), (xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin))
result[t[1]:h1+t[1],t[0]:w1+t[0]] = self.img2 # result is the output image
```

C++ Code

```
cv::warpPerspective(Stitching::img1, result, Htmat * M_left, Size((int)xmax - (int)xmin, (int)ymax - (int)ymin));
Stitching::img2.copyTo(result.colRange(t[0], w1 + t[0]).rowRange(t[1], h1 + t[1]));
```

Am I converting `result[t[1]:h1+t[1],t[0]:w1+t[0]] = self.img2` the wrong way in C++? If yes, what is the correct way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any change in `result` by executing `copyTo`?

Comment: Yes, ```result``` is the final image containing the 2 stitched images but stitching is not accurate at all even though it is accurate in python

Comment: If I were you, I'll write a simple pixel by pixel copying loop instead of the `copyTo` and check result.
If result corrected, what wrong will be usage of `copyTo`. If not, some other part will wrong.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this:

```
Stitching::img2.copyTo(result(Rect(t[0], t[1], w1, h1))
```

Regards

Comment: No difference in the results

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "the results are not the same"?

Comment: Images resulted from the python code are totally different from the images resulted from C++ code.

Comment: You mean the wrapPerspective gives different result in C++? If you save the result of the wrapPerspective (without stitching) in python and in C++ they give different images? or only the stitching is different?

Comment: No, warpPerspective gives the same results. Every step gives the exact same result. The only difference is in the output images so I suspected that the way I am blending the warped images is wrong

Comment: What type are img1,img2 and result? Mat? UMat?